# Problems With Installing Python Nmap on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, nmap

I am completely new to Ubunut and Linux so I really have no clue what I am doing wrong here. I'm copying this code out of a book I am using to learn penetration testing with python for a college course, but the code is not working. Below I have the code as I am entering it into terminal, followed by the response that it elicits. What is wrong with the code that I am entering?

```
programmer:~# wget http://zael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/python-nmap-0.3.2.tar.gz-On map.tar.gz
Resolving xael.org (xael.org)... 213.152.29.60
Connecting to xael.org (xael.org)|213.152.29.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-01-21 16:10:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2014-01-21 16:10:51--  http://nmap.tar.gz/
Resolving nmap.tar.gz (nmap.tar.gz)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `nmap.tar.gz'
```

Comment: You missed a space after .tar.gz and -On, and the page is "xael.org".

Comment: Also, please understand that the python-nmap module requires you to have Nmap installed separately. http://nmap.org/download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It because you missed a white space between link and the `-O` option , try:

```
wget http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/python-nmap-0.3.2.tar.gz
```

you could also use pip to install package

```
pip install python-nmap
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by changing the command to:
`programmer:~# wget http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/python-nmap-0.3.2.tar.gz -Onmap.tar.gz`